# Condense multiple combobox coding on Microsoft Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, combobox

I'm trying to condense the following code. I'm thinking a loop function may work, but it also may not because of the difference in VBA item. Any insight?

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox2.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox3.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox4.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox5.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox6.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox7.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox8.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox9.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox10.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox11.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox12.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox13.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If

If CheckBox14.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "Y"
    Else
    Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value = "N"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer - but the bones of a solution could include this structure

```
  Dim xCtrl As Object, dVal As Variant, xRng As Range

  For Each xCtrl In Me.Controls
    If Left(xCtrl.name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
       dVal = Val(Mid(xCtrl.name, 9))
       If dVal >= 1 And dVal < 15 Then
          If xCtrl.Value = True then
             ' ComboBox is True ... Update here
          Else
             ' ComboBox is False ... Update here
          End If
       End If
    End If
  Next xCtrl
```

Comment: Please CHECK your COMBObox ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
For i = 1 To 14
    ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").Offset(0, i - 1).End(xlUp).Value = _
       IIf(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True, "Y", "N")
Next
```

Shouldn't that `.Offset(0, 0)` be `.Offset(1, 0)` though?  Or you're just overwriting the value already there.